# Jenkins pipeline mark stage as unstable if some steps fail

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm currently facing the problem that I want to set a stage, in this case stage 2, to "UNSTABLE" if some steps fail and to "FAILED" if more then e.g. 60% of the steps are failing.

My Jenkins file currently looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("stage1") {
            steps {
                echo "prepare some stuff"
            }
        }
        stage("stage2") {
            steps {
                parallel(
                        "step1": {
                            sh 'false'
                        },
                        "step2": {
                            sh 'true'
                        },
                        "step3": {
                            sh 'false'
                        }
                )
            }
        }
        stage('stage3') {
            steps {
                echo "do some other stuff"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert. In accordance to your question, are your steps  independently from each other? For instance, if your step1 fail, step2 must start?

Comment: Hi @JRichardsz yes they are completely independend, every step must start.

Comment: Final question before my answer : Are the steps in stage2 your concern?

Comment: Yes sorry for not pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Try catch

If you want the second steps runs no mather what happen with first step, you must catch any error on first step. You could do that using a **try catch** block.

According to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43303039/3957754 , in declarative pipeline you can't just use try directly. You have to wrap arbitrary groovy code in the script step

```
stage('Maven Install') {
   steps {
       script {

           echo "Step 1"

           try {
               sh "mvn clean install"
           } catch (Exception err) {
               //increment error count
           } finally {
               //do something
           }
       }

       script {

           echo "Step 2"

           try {
               sh "mvn clean install"
           } catch (Exception err) {
               //increment error count
           } finally {
               //do something
           }
       }       
   }
}
```

## Mark stage as UNSTABLE/FAILURE

According to official documentation https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/ you could use **always** block:

```
always {
    echo 'One way or another, I have finished'
    //put here your final logic
}
```

This block will be executed when all previous stages are been e, so here you can apply some logic using the **error count** and set a state to entire build :

- currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
- currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
- etc