# When Jenkins stage get error then to do something?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want when some of the stages in the Jenkins pipeline get error then to have some options like **asking for input**, or **print some message**.

For example in this pipeline error is in the stage 2 by executing not existing 'shit' (sh 'asdasd')

```
node('master') {
  try {
    stage('stage1') {
      echo 'stage 1 succeeeded'
    }
    stage('stage2') {
      echo '1st task of stage 2 is cool'
      // this is the ERROR
      sh 'asdasd'
    }
  } finally {
      echo 'SUCCESS'
    }
}
```

**My question** is how ask for input **IF** error popup if some of the stages?

Comment: That seems like it could turn into a bowl of spaghetti. Why not just use your individual shell scripts, put those in the repo, reference those scripts and catch most of the errors there? That would make it more portable. If you ever decided to throw Jenkins out and use something else, you could use the same scripts. Just a suggestion. If you try to hard to make it succeed, maybe it really shouldn't succeed and it should fail. You might not need a popup for someone to review a failed build, but perhaps send an email, fix the build, then run it again.

Answer (score 0):

There are several posts that show how to capture errors using try - catch blocks inside anything, stages in this case: see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293501/jenkins-pipeline-try-catch-for-particular-stage-and-subsequent-conditional-ste/43303039) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003788/try-catch-block-in-jenkins-pipeline-script/50324351)

What you want additionally is define an user input in the "catch" case. In general, that is a bad idea, see [this](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/top-10-best-practices-jenkins-pipeline-plugin) article describing why user inputs are *dangerous* in pipelines. But the article also offers a solution including timeouts.

If **really** needed, code can be something like...

```js
node('master') {
  try {
    stage('stage1') {
      echo 'stage 1 succeeeded'
    }
    stage('stage2') {
      try {
        echo '1st task of stage 2 is cool'
        // this is the ERROR
        sh 'asdasd'
      } catch (errScript) {
         try {
              timeout(time: 60, unit: 'SECONDS') { // set desired timeout
                  userInput = input( id: 'userInput',
                                  message: 'Press OK to continue',
                                  )
              } 
          } catch (err) { // timeout reached or user input
             def user = err.getCauses()[0].getUser()
             if('SYSTEM' == user.toString()) { // SYSTEM means timeout.
                    // Do your timeout thing
             } else {
                    // Evaluate your user input action
             }
          }
      } // catch (errScript)
    }
  } finally {
      echo 'SUCCESS'
  }
```